# Have nuget install to directory other than package name

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

There are several questions around installing to custom directories. However, these directories all have the package name appended to them to hold package contents. For example, if I install package1.0 with a custom path of `/lib/customPackagePath`, it goes into `/lib/customPackagePath/package1.0/`.

What I want is for it to go into `/lib/customPackagePath/package/` so when I want to move forward with a new version of this package, I don't have to update every reference to content in `/lib/customPackagePath/package1.0/` to `/lib/customPackagePath/package2.0/` because package2.0 will be installed to `/lib/customPackagePath/package/` just like package1.0.

How can I tell nuget to use a custom directory and change the package name under which it is installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [`-ExcludeVersion`](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference#Install_Command) for `nuget install`:

> **-ExcludeVersion**: If set, the destination directory will contain only
>   the package name, not the version number